# FilteredList gives java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException on update

Tags: java, javafx, observablecollection, observable

I created a simple application to test filtered lists and their behavior when the corresponding source list changes. I'd like to test *update* changes also, so I created `ObservableList` of `ObservableList`s. It is faster and simpler than creating additional class like Person that have observable fields.

The code looks so:

```
    ListChangeListener<ObservableList<String>> changeNotifier = new ListChangeListener<ObservableList<String>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(Change<? extends ObservableList<String>> c) {
            while (c.next()) {
                if (c.wasPermutated()) {
                    System.out.println("permutation");
                } else if (c.wasUpdated()) {
                    System.out.println("update");
                } else {
                    if (c.wasRemoved()) {
                        System.out.println("remove");
                    }
                    if (c.wasAdded()) {
                        System.out.println("add");
                    }
                    if (c.wasReplaced()) {
                        System.out.println("replace");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
    Callback<ObservableList<String>, Observable[]> identityExtractor = new Callback<ObservableList<String>, Observable[]>() {
        @Override
        public Observable[] call(ObservableList<String> param) {
            return new Observable[]{param};
        }
    };
    Predicate<ObservableList<String>> nonEmptyFilter = new Predicate<ObservableList<String>>() {
        @Override
        public boolean test(ObservableList<String> obsl) {
            boolean nonEmpty = ! obsl.isEmpty();
            for (String item : obsl) {
                nonEmpty = nonEmpty && (null != item) && ("" != item);
            };
            return nonEmpty;
        }
    };

    ObservableList<ObservableList<String>> basicSimple = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    ObservableList<ObservableList<String>> basicComposed = FXCollections.observableArrayList( identityExtractor );

    ObservableList<ObservableList<String>> filteredSimple = basicSimple.filtered( nonEmptyFilter );
    ObservableList<ObservableList<String>> filteredComposed = basicComposed.filtered( nonEmptyFilter );

    System.out.println("Basic testing");

    System.out.println("Add invalid");
    basicSimple.addAll( FXCollections.observableArrayList("") );
    System.out.println( basicSimple );
    System.out.println( filteredSimple );

    System.out.println("Make it valid");
    basicSimple.get(0).addAll("first");
    System.out.println( filteredSimple );

    System.out.println("Add valid");
    basicSimple.addAll( FXCollections.observableArrayList("Second") );
    System.out.println( filteredSimple );

    System.out.println("Composed testing");

    System.out.println("Add invalid");
    basicComposed.addAll( FXCollections.observableArrayList("") );
    System.out.println( basicComposed );
    System.out.println( filteredComposed );

    System.out.println("Make it valid");
    basicComposed.get(0).addAll("first");
    System.out.println( filteredComposed );

    System.out.println("Add valid");
    basicComposed.addAll( FXCollections.observableArrayList("Second") );
    System.out.println( filteredComposed );
```

I've discovered a strange error during testing:

```
[info] Running helloworld.HelloWorld 
Basic testing
Add invalid
[[]]
[]
Make it valid
[]
Add valid
[[Second]]
Composed testing
Add invalid
[[]]
[]
Make it valid
[error] (JavaFX Application Thread) java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
        at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
        at javafx.collections.transformation.FilteredList.updateFilter(FilteredList.java:298)
        at javafx.collections.transformation.FilteredList.update(FilteredList.java:239)
        at javafx.collections.transformation.FilteredList.sourceChanged(FilteredList.java:137)
        at javafx.collections.transformation.TransformationList.lambda$getListener$16(TransformationList.java:106)
        at javafx.collections.transformation.TransformationList$$Lambda$63/1596532574.onChanged(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.collections.WeakListChangeListener.onChanged(WeakListChangeListener.java:88)
        at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:164)
        at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:73)
        at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.fireChange(ObservableListBase.java:233)
        at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.commit(ListChangeBuilder.java:485)
        at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.endChange(ListChangeBuilder.java:541)
        at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.endChange(ObservableListBase.java:205)
        at com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper.access$200(ObservableListWrapper.java:45)
        at com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper$1$1.invalidated(ObservableListWrapper.java:75)
        at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper$SingleInvalidation.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:126)
        at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:73)
        at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.fireChange(ObservableListBase.java:233)
        at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.commit(ListChangeBuilder.java:482)
        at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.endChange(ListChangeBuilder.java:541)
        at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.endChange(ObservableListBase.java:205)
        at javafx.collections.ModifiableObservableListBase.addAll(ModifiableObservableListBase.java:102)
        at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.addAll(ObservableListBase.java:245)
        at helloworld.HelloWorld.start(HelloWorld.java:87)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$153(LauncherImpl.java:821)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$55/7143454.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$166(PlatformImpl.java:323)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$51/397137382.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$164(PlatformImpl.java:292)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$53/1802784360.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$165(PlatformImpl.java:291)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$52/1184782272.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$45(GtkApplication.java:126)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication$$Lambda$43/450111611.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:run for the full output.
[]
Add valid
[[Second]]
```

The difference between `basicSimple` and `basicComposed` is that latter have an extractor defined, so it receives update events. In the middle of processing update event the exception was thrown by a native code. What should I consider to make the sample code work without errors?

---

#### Bit of debugging

I've inserted println to the end of the `nonEmptyFilter` predicate test. It works correctly and the ObservableList passed to it is as expected new value that was just updated. The error occurs later when some iternal code of FilteredList is executing.

Comment: Are you trying to update the filteredList?

Comment: Not, I'm updating only ArrayLists. FilteredList is updates from that automatically

Comment: The error is pretty clear `basicComposed.get(0)` doesn't exist and so the it throws `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. You can create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post, if you want us to make further investigation.

Comment: It actually exists and is printed 3 lines above the trace.

Comment: Yeah I saw that, but I can't actually see what is wrong. If you can post a MCVE it would help to further investigate

Comment: What you need to make it MVCE? Omitted main and start methods?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like a bug; I think it is probably the same as [this one](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-39710), which the bug report says is fixed for JavaFX 8u60 (presumably too late for 8u40).

I tested on 1.8.0_40-ea-b23?? and 1.9.0-ea-b49 and the error appeared in both versions. If there is currently an ea release of 1.8.0u60 I'm not sure where to find it.

Comment: Thanks, added this use case to the Jira.

Comment: Confirmed fixed in 8u60

Comment: Where did you get 8u60? I couldn't find it.

Comment: Sorry didn't get it. An Oracle engineer confirmed fix.

Answer (score 0):

So the exception gets thrown by the line `basicComposed.get(0).addAll("first");` but counter intuitively its not `get(0)` that's throwing the exception but `addAll` !?

Another thing of interest is that if you remove the `identityExtractor` then the exception goes away ?  In addition the exception is only ever thrown if `nonEmptyFilter` returns false !

So there's some kind of dynamic between the `identityExtractor` and `nonEmptyFilter` that causes `addAll` to throw the exception.

It's possible to change the current situation so that the exception is **only** thrown if **both** the following two conditions hold true:

1. `basicComposed.get(0).isEmpty()` and
2. `basicComposed.get(0).addAll("")`  // adding an empty string

Comment: How can a dynamic between identityExtractor and nonEmptyFilter exists? I printed all code here except for trivial main and strat methods. Originally I've stumbled upon this behavior in a project and reduced it to single file.

Comment: I'm guessing, but I think when the extractor is provided then the filter gets applied to it during addAll. If the result of the filter is false then the element isn't available and the exception is thrown. Again just a guess ?

Comment: Without the extractor, the filtered list won't notice the change to one of the lists contained in the underlying list (`basicComposed`). So if there is a bug in the `FilteredList` implementation, it's no surprise to me that it doesn't show up without the extractor.