# JavaFX: FilteredList last item update error

Tags: java, listview, javafx

I have a `ListView` bound with an `ObservableList<Item>`. Additionaly, I have a `ComboBox` in which I want to present only the items which are selected in the `ListView` (meaning `activeProperty` of this `Item` is set to `true`). To achieve this I bound the `ComboBox` with `FilteredList` which filters `ObservableList<Item>` according to `activeProperty`.

The problem begins when the last `Item` in the `ListView` gets deselected and selected again. In the console you can see that the item gets removed from the `FilteredList` but it does not get added when you select it back.

Also, even if the items are deselected and you can't see them in ComboBox, you can still see space for them - meaning, when you expand it, it looks like there are some 'invisible' items.

I stumbled upon [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28424864/filteredlist-gives-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-on-update) and updated my Java but it didn't solve my problem. I am running the program on build 1.8.0_66-b18.

My MVCE:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.Observable;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.collections.transformation.FilteredList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.CheckBoxListCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FilteredListTest2 extends Application {

    ObjectProperty<ObservableList<Item>> baseList;

    ObjectProperty<ObservableList<Item>> filteredList;

    ListView<Item> listView;

    ComboBox<Item> comboBox;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        initialize();

        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.getChildren().add(listView);
        root.getChildren().add(comboBox);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 160, 250);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public void initialize() {
        listView = new ListView<>();
        comboBox = new ComboBox<>();

        baseList = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
        baseList.set(FXCollections.observableArrayList(item -> 
                new Observable[] {item.activeProperty()}));
        filteredList = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
        filteredList.set(new FilteredList<>(baseList.get(), item -> item.getActive()));

        listView.itemsProperty().bind(baseList);
        listView.setCellFactory(CheckBoxListCell.forListView(
                Item::activeProperty));

        baseList.get().addListener(new ListChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(ListChangeListener.Change c) {
                if (c.next()) {
                    if (c.wasAdded()) {
                        System.out.println("base list: added " + 
                            (c.getAddedSubList()));
                    } else if (c.wasRemoved()) {
                        System.out.println("base list: removed " + 
                            (c.getRemoved()));
                    }
                }
            }});

        filteredList.get().addListener(new ListChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(ListChangeListener.Change c) {
                if (c.next()) {
                    if (c.wasAdded()) {
                        System.out.println("filtered list: added " + 
                            (c.getAddedSubList()));
                    } else if (c.wasRemoved()) {
                        System.out.println("filtered list: removed " + 
                            (c.getRemoved()));
                    }
                }
            }});

        comboBox.itemsProperty().bind(filteredList);

        baseList.get().add(new Item("1"));
        baseList.get().add(new Item("2"));
        baseList.get().add(new Item("3"));
    } 

    public static class Item {
        private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private final BooleanProperty active = new SimpleBooleanProperty(true);

        public Item(String name) {
            setName(name);
        }

        public final StringProperty nameProperty() {
            return this.name;
        }

        public final String getName() {
            return this.nameProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setName(final String name) {
            this.nameProperty().set(name);
        }

        public final BooleanProperty activeProperty() {
        return this.active;
    }

    public final boolean getActive() {
        return this.activeProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setActive(final boolean active) {
        this.activeProperty().set(active);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "name=" + getName() + ", active=" + getActive();
    }
}}
```

The output (you can see that the first and second element get removed and added just fine, the third one just gets removed - if you select it nothing happens and if you deselect it again the exception gets thrown) :

```
filtered list: removed [name=1, active=false]
filtered list: added [name=1, active=true]
filtered list: removed [name=2, active=false]
filtered list: added [name=2, active=true]
filtered list: removed [name=3, active=false]
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
    at javafx.collections.transformation.FilteredList.updateFilter(FilteredList.java:298)
    at javafx.collections.transformation.FilteredList.update(FilteredList.java:239)
    at javafx.collections.transformation.FilteredList.sourceChanged(FilteredList.java:137)
    at javafx.collections.transformation.TransformationList.lambda$getListener$16(TransformationList.java:106)
    at javafx.collections.transformation.TransformationList$$Lambda$84/2015751577.onChanged(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.collections.WeakListChangeListener.onChanged(WeakListChangeListener.java:88)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:329)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:73)
    at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.fireChange(ObservableListBase.java:233)
    at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.commit(ListChangeBuilder.java:485)
    at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.endChange(ListChangeBuilder.java:541)
    at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.endChange(ObservableListBase.java:205)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper.access$200(ObservableListWrapper.java:45)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper$1$1.invalidated(ObservableListWrapper.java:75)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:349)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(BooleanPropertyBase.java:103)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:110)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:143)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.BidirectionalBinding$BidirectionalBooleanBinding.changed(BidirectionalBinding.java:264)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.BidirectionalBinding$BidirectionalBooleanBinding.changed(BidirectionalBinding.java:227)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(BooleanPropertyBase.java:103)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:110)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:143)
    at javafx.scene.control.CheckBox.setSelected(CheckBox.java:155)
    at javafx.scene.control.CheckBox.fire(CheckBox.java:235)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3724)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3452)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1728)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2461)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:348)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:273)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:382)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:553)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:925)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(WinApplication.java:102)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$37/96639997.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: You have mentioned that you have an update error. So please update the question with the console out-put as we all can figure out what your error is.

Comment: @MadushanPerera updated

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code . Everything works fine. `java version "1.8.0_66"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-b17)
`

Comment: @MadushanPerera Have you tried selecting and deselecting the last element on the list a couple of times? this is where the exception is thrown in my case and I'm running the same Java version.

Comment: Yes. Many times but got no errors. :)

Comment: @MadushanPerera Well this is most irregular. Thank you for showing interest anyway.